# Can't get display attribute

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to get `display` attribute about an element using `style.display`. But its not returning anything.
Have a look at the JsFiddle one.

http://jsfiddle.net/4v5LS/1/

There is nothing in the alert window.

**UPDATE**

Now I just noticed something unusual. Whenever I define the properties inline then things do work. But when I apply style in any other method, then its not working.

Comment: The *style.display* property returns values set directly on the element, not inherited (or computed) values.

Comment: But the `box` div is not inside any other div. And I specified the `display` in the CSS. So what is to be computed here ? I am not getting a grasp on this fact.

Comment: Element styling is computed based on styles directly on the element, those inherited from parent elements and those calculated from CSS. The style object only holds values for properties set directly on the element. All the rest (including those from CSS) are computed. Have a look at the marked duplicate.

Comment: Oh. Okay. I got it now. Thanks a lot. It was very very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle)

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
     element = document.getElementById('box');
     style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
     display = style.getPropertyValue('display');
    alert(display);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4v5LS/6/)

Comment: Please don't post code–only answers. Explain what the OP did wrong and why your answer "works".

Comment: Everytime i tried to do this always other users post answers faster than me and i spended my time to answer to OP for nothing ;)

Comment: There is nothing to stop you from editing your answer to add more detail.

Comment: I posted my answer and after 15 secs(sorry can't remember exacly) you downvote me for that reason. Didn't have time to react :). Another time when i posted my answer and after i started edit it to explain why i posted the code another user blamed me that i edit my first post and this is not right :/ anyway Thx @RobG i will follow your advice in future :)

Comment: I didn't down vote you. If you edit your post, whoever did can remove the down vote (if they come back…).