# Why ican't it find the display property? (more below)

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I added a event listener to a button, which would show the css of the #popUpForm, however on the console it logs nothing.

**markup:**

```
<input id = "addItem" type = button value = "+">
                
<div id = "popUpForm">
    /* lot of divs*/
</div>
```

**script:**

```
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#addItem')

addBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(document.querySelector('#popUpForm').style.display)
})
```

**css:**

```
#popUpForm{
    width: 350px;
    height: 500px;

    display:none;  <-- looking for this
}
```

I'm using **webpack**, is it possible, that somehow it messes up my code? Any help appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080150/cant-get-display-attribute, check here for the answer

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes, please pick an answer. If not, please comment accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`element.style`refers to **inline styles only**.

To check for currently applied styles regardless of the source, use

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#popUpForm')).display
```

instead. Beware that this a very expensive call performance-wise, so only ever use it when no better solution is available.

That being said, I'd suggest working with the API for the job, which is the [`hidden` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden), which would simplify the check for visibility to

```
document.querySelector('#popUpForm').hidden
```

Especially, this makes it very easy to toggle visibility:

```
document.querySelector('#popUpForm').hidden = !document.querySelector('#popUpForm').hidden
```